# Guidelines to generate Authorization Code for Credit Card transactions

Tags: c#, credit-card, iso8583

I'm working on a module that will receive the messages in a custom format with all the information required to process the request (Purchase, Cash Disbursement, Balance Inquiry), so in order to compose the response, i have to generate the authorization code (Field 38 - ISO8583), only if the transaction was processed sucessfully.

As i know, it doesn't have to be unique, but i don't know if any other values from the transaction must be used to generate it.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: what exactly is your question?  what have you tried? what errors did you get?

Comment: Well, Is it there any specific algorithm to generate it? or can be done with just a random number of 6 digits based on time? What is the best approach?

Comment: Are you using an authorization provider? or are you hoping to BE the provider?  How are you debiting the credit cards?

Comment: A google search reveals [this sourceforge project](http://niso8583.sourceforge.net/).  Have you seen it?

Comment: This module will be integrated within issuer's transactional system and debits are going to be made through data queues. That platform already generates an authorization code of 8 digits length, but i want to be sure if take a part of it will not be a bad practice.

Comment: Yes, I've see it before. It's basically for pack or unpack the messages, i guess this does not generate this kind of values or am i wrong? I'll take a look again on it.

Comment: I've only ever seen the provider generate the code, its then passed through the middle man (you in this case) and on to the consumer.  I dont think this would be bad practice.  It would be one number that you could use to identify the whole series of transactions.

Comment: Yes, I'll do that. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Mind if i throw it in as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only ever seen the provider generate the code, its then passed through the middleman (you in this case) and on to the consumer.

I don't think this would be bad practice. It would be one number that you could use to identify the whole series of transactions.